# invalid xsd- SAXParseException

Tags: xml, xsd

I´m currently working with xsd and tried to define a simple XSD file, for an order with some order-items. But i´m getting a SAXParseException, if i validate the xsd file. Who can see the problem? I can´t get it fixed so far :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="order">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name='orderId' type='xs:string' use='required'/>
        <xs:attribute name='orderDate' type='xs:date' use='required'/>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='orderItem' type='OrderItem'/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name='OrderItem'>
   <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name='title' type='xs:string'/>
        <xs:element name='manufacturer' type='Company'/>
        <xs:element name='quantity' type='xs:positiveInteger'/>
        <xs:element name='price' type='xs:decimal'/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name='Company'>
    <xs:element name='name' type='xs:string'/>
    <xs:element name='adress' type='Adress'/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Adress">
    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

and there´s a sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<order orderId='1001' orderDate='2015-05-22'>
    <orderItem>
        <title>Nikon D5200</title>
        <manufacturer>
            <name>Nikon</name>
            <adress>
                <street>Hauptstr. 12</street>
                <city>Mannheim</city>
                <zip>68161</zip>
                <country>DE</country>
            </adress>
        </manufacturer>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>559.25</price>
    </orderItem>
</order>
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/andre/Documents/dtd/order.xsd; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 16; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: Content from "#AnonType_order" is invalid. Element "sequence" is invalid, occurs too often or on wrong place.

**Edit: Another mystery for me, is when do i need a  ? I used it in the  tag, so i can insert several  tags, which makes sense. But is it needed in the  tag definition? Cause one orderItem object should have only one title and so on- so do i need there a  tag around?**

Comment: Edit: Another mystery for me, is when do i need a <xs:sequence> ? I used it in the <order> tag, so i can insert several <orderitem> tags, which makes sense. But is it needed in the <OrderItem> tag definition? Cause one orderItem object should have only one title and so on- so do i need there a <sequence> tag around?

Comment: In your input XML, you have written `</zip>68161</zip>`, it should be `<zip>68161</zip>`.

Comment: Yes, i did :) But the problem is in the xsd- cause online xsd validators throwing same exception on the xsd-file.

Comment: yes you need ad <sequence> tag around, having an element under a complexType is invalid. You can use a XSD editor that will give you hints on what you are allowed to write, or at worst you can try to validate your xsd against http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because your schema is not correctly built.

### For element *order*

The `xs:sequence` must come before `xs:attribute` declaration. The correct version is:

```
<xs:element name="order">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='orderItem' type='OrderItem'/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name='orderId' type='xs:string' use='required'/>
        <xs:attribute name='orderDate' type='xs:date' use='required'/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

### For the complexTypes *Company* and *Address*

you must use the `xs:sequence` to specify you want the element to appear in a specific order. It should be corrected that way

```
<xs:complexType name='Company'>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='name' type='xs:string'/>
      <xs:element name='adress' type='Adress'/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Adress">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

These are very basic features. You are strongly advised to read any tutorial on XML Schema to get acquainted on this.